# How to whitelist boolean true/false or string 'true'/'false'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, busboy

Is there a way to whitelist a property value in expressjs?  IE I would like to limit a properties values to either a Boolean true/false or the string 'true'/'false'.

Because truthy sucks in JS I cannot just do this

```
  var foo = Boolean(req.param('foo'));
```

Since the string 'false' evaluates to true.

Looking to simplify this, however also wondering if there is something built in to expressjs or multer/busboy that I am missin:

```
var fooParam = req.param('foo');
var foo;
if (fooParam === 'true' || fooParam === 'false') {
  foo = fooParam === 'true;
} else if (fooParam === true || fooParam === false) {
  foo = fooParam;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, when can it be boolean instead of string `true`/`false`? JSON request bodies?

Comment: And to clarify, the three results are: `'true'` or `true` produces `foo = true`, `'false'` or `false` produces `foo = false`, and any other strings or types produce `foo = undefined`?

Comment: How about using `typeof fooParam === 'boolean'` in the second `if`?

Comment: @Ry- yes trying to simply a route that can use multipart/form-data and application/json.  JSON would of course be a boolean, but multipart values are strings so would come in as 'true'/'false'.

Comment: There’s really no super-clean solution to this, just variations on the same thing you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this notation:

```
[true, false, 'true', 'false'].includes(req.param('foo'))
```

It offers great extensibility.

```
let result: boolean | undefined = undefined;
if ([false, 'false'].includes(req.param('foo'))) {
  result = false;
} else if ([true, 'true'].includes(req.param('foo'))) {
  result = true;
}
```

Comment: But strings other than `'false'` would also result in `false`, while in the author code they would be `undefined`

Comment: There you go, I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to tackle it in the opposite direction - stringify the provided value and check the resulting string:

```
var fooParam = req.param('foo');
// map the string value of each boolean to the corresponding boolean value
var boolMap = new Map([['true', true], ['false', false]]); 
// stringify the provided param (true\'true' => 'true', false\'false' => 'false') 
// and get the corresponding value from the mapping. 
// in case of value that is not true\'true'\false\'false' was provided, undefined will be assigned to foo.
var foo = boolMap.get(String(fooParam));
```

Comment: Using an object with a prototype has the issue that `fooParam === 'hasOwnProperty'`, `'toString'`, etc. will give unexpected results. (Sometimes this is even a vulnerability.) A `Map` might be better.

Comment: @Ry- I agree. Thanks for the comment, edited the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
let maChaine = true;
let monBooleen = JSON.parse(maChaine); 
console.log(monBooleen); //monBoolen vaut true

maChaine = 'true';
monBooleen = JSON.parse(maChaine); 
console.log(monBooleen); //monBoolen vaut true

maChaine = false;
monBooleen = JSON.parse(maChaine); 
console.log(monBooleen); //monBoolen vaut false

maChaine = 'false';
monBooleen = JSON.parse(maChaine); 
console.log(monBooleen); //monBoolen vaut false
```

so, your code will be:

```
var fooParam = req.param('foo');
let foo = [true, false, 'true', 'false'].includes(fooParam)?JSON.parse(fooParam):undefined
```

Comment: There‘s a lot more valid JSON than just `'true'` and `'false'` though. `'1'`, `'null'`, `'{}'`, `[]`, `'"foo"'` will all give unexpected results.